# One table occupying available height of cell in other table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

The situation is somewhat like this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="left" id="t1" style="width: 30%">
                    ....
                </table>
                <table align="left" id="t2" style="width: 70%">
                    ....
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now there are lesser contents in table `#t1` than `#t2`. So the height of their parent `<td>` is decided by the amount of content in `#t2`

Is there a way to center align `#t1` or to make `#t1` occupy the whole available height?

Have already tried `vertical-align` on them.. no success yet.

Can change the markup. but cannot replace `<table>` by `<div>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? Your code is not express the samething what you have told?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#t1 td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I tried this.. that's not working. What's happening here is the table `#t1` is not occupying the available height. And thus its stuck to top.

Comment: Then you need to apply the same rule to the cell in which you put your t1 table.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had not provided any height to the parent table. Anyway thanks :)